# How dangerous is this? (List<T> being cast to List<const T>)

Tags: c++, c++11

Usually I only use `reinterpret_cast` to do something low-level and "magical", I then create a test-case to ensure it works on the system at compile-time.

```
operator list<const T>&() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<list<const T>*>(this);
}
```

Is this safe? This isn't a stupid cast and I cannot see any reason for this to be dangerous, however I am not using it in some very specific case, I use lists in a lot of places....

So yes, I can see no reason why it isn't safe in this specific case.

The class uses virtual functions (so `enable_if` and other meta-programming can't get in the way, as you can't mix virtual and templates (thus SFINAE)) so I really think it should be fine, can someone confirm?

Comment: Since you return a mutable lvalue, someone could append a `const T` element. And someone else still can access the original `list<T>`, assuming *all* elements are modifiable. Essentially the same problem why `T**` cannot be converted to `T const**`.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you've added a partial specialisation to force an inheritance relationship between `list<T>` and `list<const T>`, they are two completely distinct types. Standard C++ doesn't allow you to just pretend one type really is another type, and since C++ doesn't allow it, compilers have taken the liberty of optimising based on the assumption that you don't do it. When you break that assumption, you can get all sorts of wonderful inexplicable results.

But since this is your own class, you *can* force such an inheritance relationship: just make `list<T>` derive from `list<const T>`, let `list<const T>` do all the work, and have `list<T>` provide a few additional required methods to modify the contained data.

Comment: I like this, is there a way to make it play nice with virtuals? (eg `linked_list<const T>` and `linked_list<T>` deriving from each other nicely such that `list<const T>&` is a cast to a base of `linked_list<T>` - I'm not at home ATM to test anything you see)

Comment: @AlecTeal I suppose you could make that work, but that might get you a case of multiple inheritance (`linked_list<T>` deriving from `linked_list<const T>` and `list<T>`, both of which derive from `list<const T>`), unless you let go of some of that hierarchy. Unfortunately, all approaches I can some up with right now have significant drawbacks, and without more info on your requirements, I'm having a lot of trouble weighing the pros and cons.

Comment: @AlecTeal: I imagine that `list<T>` is just an interface, then you can use virtual inheritance and it will play *nice*. At any rate, you could also argue whether inheritance at the container level really makes sense... it seems that you are using OO (inheritance) where generic programming (templates) could make more sense...

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is free to assume that such a cast will never occur.

Suppose you have some code that can be proven will never run if `T` is `const T`.  Then the compiler is free to eliminate it from `list<const T>`.  If that code was the only code that accessed some `private` `bool` in `list<const T>`, then the compiler is free to eliminate that `bool` by the as-if rule, as the only way to access it involves undefined behavior (such as your cast or the like).

That kind of thing can lead to `list<const T>` having a very different memory layout than `list<T>`.

Does your compiler ever do this?  Maybe not.  Will future versions of your compiler ever do this?  You cannot tell, because those future versions haven't been written yet.

Comment: The memory layout isn't changed between `list<const T>` and `list<T>` as I mention even the vtables had an identical layout. - If it was I wouldn't be asking this question

Comment: @AlecTeal the memory layout wasn't changed in your current compiler and version.  Next patch?  Who knows.

Comment: `template<class T> struct thing { T data; }`, are you saying `thing<T>` and `thing<const T>` will change size? Exactly.

Comment: No, `template<class T> struct thing { void setT( T t ){data=t;} T getT() const { return data; } private: T data = 0; };` -- the compiler would be justified in `thing<int>` being 4 bytes and `thing<const int>` being 1 byte, because via the as-if rule, the `data` in `thing` need not exist, and because we are not standard layout (we have `private`) we can mess with object layouts at will.  The short version is: you are doing undefined behavior, the compiler could format your harddrive and follow the standard.  The above is just one possible practical example of how it could screw up.